# How to use OR in sql IN()

Tags: sql

I can run sql query like

```
select * from table1 where subject1 in ('Physics', 'chemistry')
```

Now I have two columns of subjects. Can it be modified as

```
select * from table1  where subject1 or subject2 in ('Physics', 'chemistry')
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you need two separate clauses:

```
select *
from table1
where subject1 in ('Physics', 'chemistry') or
      subject2 in ('Physics', 'chemistry');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> select * from table1 where subject1 in ('Physics', 'chemistry') or subject2 in ('Physics', 'chemistry')

I'm rusty on SQL but I think that'll work.